# Android ImageView Fixing Image Size

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an Android Application, where I have an `ImageView`, I need to keep the size constant, there can be various images that I need to put into this `ImageView`, of different sizes.

I just need to ensure that all the Images must fit into the `ImageView`,
the Image should increase in size if it is smaller and should decrease, in case it is bigger.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Post the code with what have you tried.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Fix ImageView's size with `dp` or `fill_parent` and set `android:scaleType` to `fitXY`.

Answer (score 56):

In your case you need to

1. Fix the ImageView's size. 
   You need to use **dp** unit so that it will look the same in all devices.
2. Set `android:scaleType` to `fitXY`

Below is an example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/iclauncher" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

For more information regarding ImageView scaleType please refer to [the developer website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: Why `fitXY`? and why not using `minHeight` and `minWidth` instead of layout_x ?

Comment: I had everything fitting in the XML Layout, and setImageResource broke the scaling even when the replacement was identical in size.  Adding scaleType="fitXY" fixed it perfectly!

Comment: What worked for me is scaleType="fitCenter", to ensure the image x/y ratio is kept.

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
ImageView img
    Bitmap bmp;
    int width=100;
    int height=100;
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);//image is your image                                                            
    bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width,height, true);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**Or**
If you want to load complete image size in memory then you can use

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this, suppose if you want to make a back image button and you have "500x500 png" and want it to fit in small button size.

## Use dp to fix  ImageView's size.

add this line of code to your Imageview.

android:scaleType="fitXY"

EXAMPLE:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/Backicon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this helped me.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:scaleType` and set `fitXY` in XML unless you add `layout_width` & `layout_height` attributes.
**Example**:
`android:scaleType="fitXY"`

If you want to add programmatically,
**Example**:
`youriv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a clear answer yet. `ImageView` is not resizing to image size every image loads.