# Why is this image not stretching even when I set the height to over 1000dp?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have started learning android yesterday from Udacity and have no prior experience in coding or programming. I want this image to fill all the gap and stretch out. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ImageView Fixing Image Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049626/android-imageview-fixing-image-size)

Comment: NEVER post images of code! [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to use scaleType
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

In your case try android:scaleType="fitXY"or android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Visual guide:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Answer (score 2):

Use match parent as width and height to **fit parent container** (screen) and **scaleType = fitXY**

To make image fit all size

Like this code below:

```
   <imageView
   android:src="@drowble/mountains"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ImageView tag , you can use `android:scaleType = "manyOptions"`.

Scroll through the possible option and choose the one that is right for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```